# Running a collection group query to see if a field in my firebase subcollection is true or false

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm creating a sign in method that is trying to check if my current user has agreed to my terms of agreement after verifying their email address. My function is as follows:

```
SignIn(email, password) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(cred => {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
                // Gets current signed in user.
                this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
                    // Queries Details subcollection.
            this.db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('Details')
                        .get().toPromise().then(
                            doc => {
                                if (user.termsOfAgreement == false) {
                                    this.router.navigate(['terms']);
                                } else {
                                    this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
                                }
                            })
                })
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            window.alert(error.message)
        })
}
```

I know that I'm getting the firebase user object and that it doesn't contain my specific sub collection field names (i.e. user.termsOfAgreement). But how would I access those? I'm trying to check if my termsOfAgreement field is true or false.

My Firestore User Collection state on sign up

```
User (Collection)
- lastLogin: timestamp
- name: string
- userId: string

Details (subcollection)
- termsOfAgreement: false
```

Answer (score 1):

First note that `this.db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('Details')` is **not** a collection group query, but a read operation on a single collection.

It sounds like you want to check if the `Details` collection under the user document contains a document with `termsOfAgreement` equal to true. You can most easily check that with:

```
firebase.firestore()
        .collection('users').doc(user.uid)
        .collection('Details').where('termsOfAgreement', '==', true).limit(1)
        .get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            if (querySnapshot.empty == false) {
                this.router.navigate(['terms']);
            } else {
                this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
            }
        })
```

The above code is using the regular JavaScript SDK, as there is no need to use AngularFire for this operation. But aside from that, it'd work the same in either: you fire a query against the collection and then check if there's any results.

In addition to fixing your code, this also optimizes it in two ways:

1. The query is sent to the server, so that you're only transferring data that matches the condition.
2. At most one document is transferred, since you only care whether any result exists.

---

I'm not sure why you're storing `termsOfAgreement` in the subcollection though.

If you're checking for the existence of any subdocument where the `termsOfAgreement` is true, you might want to consider adding a `termsOfAgreement` field to the user document itself, so that you don't need to perform a query across the subcollection.

You'd set this `userDoc.termsOfAgreement` to true once the user accepts any terms in the subcollection, and then won't have to query the subcollection anymore (simplifying the reading code and reducing the number of read operations).

Comment: Hey Frank, Thank you so much for this guidance. I'm still getting used to coming over from SQL to NoSQL. I'll bring the subcollection up to the main document level. That makes more sense after you explained it.